# Convert between SqlGeometry and DbGeometry

Tags: c#, geospatial, sqlgeometry

Is there a simple way to convert between SqlGeometry and DbGeometry?
I'm using a popular sql spatial helper library and all of the functions in there expect SqlGeometry. But when i use Entity Framework against an ESRI ArcSDE feature class the Shape field is returned as a DbGeometry.
I can't call any of the methods I would like to (such as LocateAlongGeom) with that DbGeometry type.
Maybe there is a way to serialize it as binary or text then read it back in as a SqlGeometry?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
//Convert from SqlGeometry to DbGeometry 
SqlGeometry sqlGeo = ...
DbGeometry dbGeo = DbGeometry.FromBinary(sqlGeo.STAsBinary().Buffer);

//Convert from DBGeometry to SqlGeometry
 SqlGeometry sqlGeo2 = SqlGeometry.STGeomFromWKB(new SqlBytes(dbGeo.AsBinary()), 0);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `DbGeometry` to `SqlGeometry` conversion be... `SqlGeometry sqlGeo2 = SqlGeometry.STGeomFromWKB(new SqlBytes(dbGeo.AsBinary()), dbGeo.CoordinateSystemId);`
To account for geometries that aren't in SRID-0?

Comment: Yes, I would assume you'd want to pass in the SRID in most cases. For most GPS coordinates you'd use `4326` for WGS84. http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/

Comment: I believe you can also detect it dynamically using `dbGeo.CoordinateSystemId` in place of the zero above.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to manage multiple spatial types is via extension methods, like so: (using slightly modified versions of the code samples from @BizarroDavid)

```
public static class GeometryExtensions
{
    public static DbGeometry ToDbGeometry(this SqlGeometry sqlGeometry)
    {
        return DbGeometry.FromBinary(sqlGeometry.STAsBinary().Buffer);
    }

    public static SqlGeometry ToSqlGeometry(this DbGeometry dbGeometry)
    {
        return SqlGeometry.STGeomFromWKB(new SqlBytes(dbGeometry.AsBinary()), dbGeometry.CoordinateSystemId);
    }
}
```

Once you have them implemented, you can use them like so...

```
DbGeometry anyDbGeometry;
SqlGeometry anySqlGeometry;

//Convert to DbGeometry
anyDbGeometry = anySqlGeometry.ToDbGeometry();

//Convert to SqlGeometry
anySqlGeometry = anyDbGeometry.ToSqlGeometry();
```

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework doesn't support CURVES (CIRCLE) -> change to lines:

```
return DbGeometry.FromBinary(sqlGeometry.**STCurveToLine()**.STAsBinary().Buffer);
```